# Second MPI_Send between Parent and Child processes hangs

Tags: c, mpi, send, spawn, recv

I am testing communication between the Parent and Child processes. Parent spawns one child and `MPI_Send`'s two messages. Child process correspondingly `MPI_Recv`'s from the Parent twice. Depending on where I run the code, it either works (MacOS) or hangs after the second `MPI_Send` (Ubuntu).

Any help would be much appreciated. The test code is as follows:

`master.c`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    MPI_Comm children;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 

    MPI_Comm_spawn("worker", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1,
             MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &children,  
             MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

    int send = 777;
    MPI_Send(&send, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, children);
    printf("Sent: %d\n", send);

    send = 111;
    MPI_Send(&send, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, children);
    printf("Sent: %d\n", send);

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

`worker.c`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    MPI_Comm parent; 
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent); 

    int recv;
    MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, parent, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Received: %d\n", recv);

    MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, parent, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Received: %d\n", recv);

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I tested this on Open MPI versions: 4.0.0, 3.0.0 and 3.1.3. The code was compiled with `mpicc master.c -o master`, `mpicc worker.c -o worker` and run with `mpirun -n 1 master`.

The desired output would be:

```
Sent: 777
Received: 777
Sent: 111
Received: 111
```

However, when MPI hangs, the code prints:

```
Sent: 777
Received: 777
```

Probably worth mentioning is that if I put in the Parent process one `MPI_Recv` between two `MPI_Send`'s, and a corresponding `MPI_Send` in the Child process, the code works and does not hang.

Comment: try selecting a single TCP interface. For example, `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self --mca btl_tcp_if_include 192.168.0.0/24 -np 1 ./master`

Comment: That worked, i.e. setting a device for MPI communication solved the problem (for me `mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_include 127.0.0.1/131 -np 1 master` has done it). Thanks!